# How to get records ordered by joined table field

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
chat:
id
name

chat_messages:
id
chat_id
user_id
message
created_at
```

I want to get a list of chats names ordered by recent activity. In other words, I want to get a list of chats where the first one is that with the bigger created_at field, and the last one is that with the smaller created_at field.

For example:

```
chat table:
1 General
2 News

chat_messages:
1 | 1 | 20 | Hello everybody | 2020-10 18:00:00
1 | 1 | 23 | this is a me... | 2020-10 18:00:05
1 | 1 | 15 | another message | 2020-10 18:00:15
1 | 2 | 22 | Anybody there?  | 2020-10 17:00:00
1 | 2 | 45 | Hello?????????? | 2020-10 16:00:00
```

The desired result would be: ['News', 'General']

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: ok, I have write down an example. Thanks

Comment: I refer you to my previous comment

Comment: Sorry perhaps my english is not good enough to understand. I don't know why my details seems to be insufficient... Lot of instructions and rules for a simple question!

Comment: Is three a lot? OK.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: By the way the dates lack days

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `chat`.`name`
FROM `chat` JOIN `chat_message` ON `chat`.`id` = `chat_message`.`chat_id`
ORDER BY `chat_message`.`created_at` DESC
```

Explanation:

You only want the chat name to be returned. And you also want each value only once (that's the `DISTINCT`).

You `ORDER BY` the `created_at` field, and then the only thing left to do is to `JOIN` the tables.

**Edit**: you can try / improve [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/597386/4/0).

Answer (score 2):

Select last Created_at for every chat:

```sql
  SELECT m.chat_id,
         max(m.created_at) as LastActivity
    FROM chat_message as m
group by m.chat_id;
```

Let's find some infos about chats, by joining the chat table:

```sql
SELECT c.name,
       info.LastActivity
  FROM (  SELECT m.chat_id,
             max(m.created_at) as LastActivity
        FROM chat_message as m
    group by m.chat_id) info -- virtual table "info" from first query
  JOIN chat as c ON c.id = info.chat_id; -- add table chat to query
```

Now we want to add some info about the LastActivity

```sql
SELECT c.name,
       info.LastActivity,
       m2.user_id, -- Print Infos of LastActivityMessage
       m2.message
  FROM (  SELECT m.chat_id,
             max(m.created_at) as LastActivity
        FROM chat_message as m
    group by m.chat_id) info
  JOIN chat as c ON c.id = info.chat_id
  JOIN chat_message as m2 ON info.LastActivity = m2.created_at; -- Search for Message at LastActivity
```

In out last query we see a problem: We do not want to search for a messag with it's date!
We're missing a propper primary-Key in table `chat_message`.

I'd suggest to calculate a unique id:

```sql
create table chat_message
(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key, -- this is the message-id which will automatically set
    chat_id int not null, -- where did the user post?
    user_id int not null, -- which user?
    message text,
    created_at datetime
);
```

If we insert our Messages now like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO chat_message (chat_id, user_id, message, created_at) 
  VALUES
  (2, 45, "Hello?", "2020-10-01 16:00:00"),
  (2 , 22 , "Anybody there?"  , "2020-10-01 17:00:00"),
  (1, 20, "Hello everybody", "2020-10-01 18:00:00"),
  (1, 23,  "this is a me...", "2020-10-01 18:00:05"),
  (1, 15, "another message", "2020-10-01 18:00:15");
```

..Ids are generated automatically:

```
id  chat_id user_id message         created_at
1   2       45      Hello?          2020-10-01T16:00:00Z
2   2       22      Anybody there?  2020-10-01T17:00:00Z
3   1       20      Hello everybody 2020-10-01T18:00:00Z
4   1       23      this is a me... 2020-10-01T18:00:05Z
5   1       15      another message 2020-10-01T18:00:15Z
```

This leads to a better query without searching for a single message with it's date:

```sql
-- Now we want to add some info about the LastActivity
SELECT c.name,
       m2.id,
       m2.created_at,
       m2.user_id,
       m2.message
  FROM (  SELECT m.chat_id,
             max(m.id) as LastActivity -- select last Id
        FROM chat_message as m
    group by m.chat_id) info
  JOIN chat as c ON c.id = info.chat_id
  JOIN chat_message as m2 ON info.LastActivity = m2.id; -- search for message with correct id
```